# Activation Error while testing Exception Handling Application Block

Tags: logging, exception, enterprise-library

I'm getting the following error while testing my EHAB implementation:

**ArgumentException - Event log names must consist of printable characters and cannot contain , *, ?, or spaces**

The stack trace was:

> {"Activation error occured while
>   trying to get instance of type
>   ExceptionPolicyImpl, key "LogPolicy""}
>   System.Exception Stack Trace:
>   StackTrace "   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   53     at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String
>   key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   103     at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicy.GetExceptionPolicy(Exception
>   exception, String policyName) in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\ExceptionHandling\Src\ExceptionHandling\ExceptionPolicy.cs:line
>   131     at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(Exception
>   exceptionToHandle, String policyName)
>   in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\ExceptionHandling\Src\ExceptionHandling\ExceptionPolicy.cs:line
>   55     at
>   Blackbox.Exception.ExceptionMain.LogException(Exception
>   pException) in C:_Work_Black
>   Box\Blackbox.Exception\ExceptionMain.vb:line
>   14     at
>   BlackBox.Business.BusinessMain.TestExceptionHandling()
>   in C:_Work_Black
>   Box\BlackBox.Business\BusinessMain.vb:line
>   16     at
>   Blackbox.Service.Service1.TestExceptionHandling()
>   in C:_Work_Black
>   Box\Blackbox.Service\Service.svc.vb:line
>   43" String Inner Exception: 
>   InnerException {"Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl",
>   name = "LogPolicy". Exception occurred
>   while: Calling constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener(System.String
>   source, System.String log,
>   System.String machineName,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter
>   formatter). Exception is:
>   ArgumentException - Event log names
>   must consist of printable characters
>   and cannot contain \, *, ?, or spaces

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl,LogPolicy
  Resolving parameter "policyEntries" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl(System.String policyName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] policyEntries)
    Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry,LogPolicy.All Exceptions
    Resolving parameter "handlers" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry(System.Type exceptionType, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.PostHandlingAction postHandlingAction, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] handlers, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Instrumentation.IExceptionHandlingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider)
      Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler,LogPolicy.All Exceptions.Logging Exception Handler (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, LogPolicy.All Exceptions.Logging Exception Handler)
      Resolving parameter "writer" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler(System.String logCategory, System.Int32 eventId, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType severity, System.String title, System.Int32 priority, System.Type formatterType, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter writer)
        Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl,LogWriter.__default__ (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter, (none))
        Resolving parameter "structureHolder" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder structureHolder, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator updateCoordinator)
          Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,LogWriterStructureHolder.__default__ (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder, (none))
          Resolving parameter "traceSources" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] filters, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceSourceNames, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceSources, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource allEventsTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource notProcessedTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource errorsTraceSource, System.String defaultCategory, System.Boolean tracingEnabled, System.Boolean logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch, System.Boolean revertImpersonation)
            Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,General
            Resolving parameter "traceListeners" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource(System.String name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceListeners, System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels level, System.Boolean autoFlush, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider)
              Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper,Event Log Listener (mapped from System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Event Log Listener)
              Resolving parameter "wrappedTraceListener" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper(System.Diagnostics.TraceListener wrappedTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator coordinator)
                Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener,Event Log Listener‌implementation (mapped from System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Event Log Listener‌implementation)
                Calling constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener(System.String source, System.String log, System.String machineName, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter formatter)
"} System.Exception

My web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="C:\Blackbox.log" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="LogPolicy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
                priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="WcfExceptionShielding">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="InvalidOperationException" type="System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF.FaultContractExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                exceptionMessageResourceType="" exceptionMessageResourceName="This is the message"
                exceptionMessage="This is the exception" faultContractType="Blackbox.Service.WCFFault, Blackbox.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
                name="Fault Contract Exception Handler">
                <mappings>
                  <add source="{Guid}" name="Id" />
                  <add source="{Message}" name="MessageText" />
                </mappings>
              </add>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompassEntities" connectionString="metadata=~\bin\CompassModel.csdl|~\bin\CompassModel.ssdl|~\bin\CompassModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=foo;Password=foo;Server=foo64mo;Home=OraClient11g_home1;Persist Security Info=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="BlackboxEntities" connectionString="metadata=~\bin\BlackboxModel.csdl|~\bin\BlackboxModel.ssdl|~\bin\BlackboxModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=sqldev1\cps;Initial Catalog=FundServ;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

My code is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function LogException(ByVal pException As System.Exception) As Boolean
        Return ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(pException, "LogPolicy")
    End Function
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log property is wrong.   Is supposed to point to the event log.  So it would be "BlackBox" or "Application"

```
 <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
    log="Blackbox" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack" />
```

If you want to write to a file, use the

```
  listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData
```